# I need a decent alternative to c++

Tags: programming-languages

I've learned php and c++, i will list the things i liked and didn't liked on each of them, how i decided to learn them in the first place and why i feel the need to learn a decent alternative to c++, i'm not a professional programmer and only do projects for myself.

**PHP -** Decided to learn because i wanted to build a dynamic website, that i did and turned out very good, i even coded a 'not so basic' search engine for it that would display the results 'google style' and really fast, pretty cool stuff.

**PROS -** Pretty consistent syntax for all stuff (minor caveats), great functionality, a joy for me to code in it (it seems to 'know' what i want it to do and just does it)

**CONS -** Painfully slow for number crunching (which takes me to c++ that i only learned because i wanted to do some number crunching and it had to be screaming fast)

**C++ -** Learned because number crunching was so slow in php and manipulating large amounts of data was very difficult, i thought, it's popular programming language and all, and tests show that it's fast, the basic stuff resemble php so it shouldn't be hard to pick up

**PROS -** It can be used to virtually anything, very very fast

**CONS -** Although fun to code at the start, if i need to do something out of the ordinary, memory allocation routines, pointer stuff, stack sizes etc... will get me tired really quick, syntax is a bit inconsistent some times (more caveats)

I guess that from what i wrote you guys will understand what i'm looking for, there are thousands of languages out there, it's likely that one of them will suit my needs, i've been seeing stuff today and a friend of mine that is a professional programmer tried OCaml and Fortran and said that both are fast for numerical stuff, i've been inclined to test Fortran, but i need some more input because i want to have some other good 'candidates' to choose from, for example the python syntax seemed great to me, but then i found out from some tests that it was a lot slower than c++ and i simply don't want to twiddle my thumbs all day.

Comment: So you tried C++ and it wasn't working out for you. That's not unusual. But why the heck did you think to try *PHP* next? It's like trying to learn classical guitar and giving up for Guitar Hero.

Comment: D never gets any love :(

Comment: @joshin4colours No i didn't left c++ to php, quite the contrary

Comment: @You If it's any good i'll love it, maybe you could respond to my question if you think D fits my needs and ellaborate a bit.

Comment: Try C++11, it fixed many of the original C++ pains

Comment: Memory handling tiring you? Odd. I have written C++ for years with rarely ever having to type `new`, and never `delete`. Maybe you just _think_ you have learned C++?

Comment: @sbi Because you are just an AWESOME programmer and everyone in the civilized world dreams of being like you, isn't it?

Comment: @sbi: I'm a hardcore C++ engineer and love the language. However, sometimes us C++ people need to lift our heads and look around. While I share some of your sentiment, I have observed other engineers who came and have gone through our team. The truth is that people can crank out C# code WAY more efficiently than C++ because in C++ there's just way too many times they get stuck with some weird bug (usually memory/pointer related) that would set them back hours if not days and when those bugs reach QA or production they set can them back weeks at a time.

Comment: @DXM: Mostly because only people who don't know how to RAII come up with those bugs.

Comment: @DeadMG: RAII is certainly a factor, but it's not the whole story. Our team code reviews 95% of everything that is checked in. We use smart pointers as much as possible and it is extremely hard for operator new to slip into the code. Nevertheless, C++ simply gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot and sooner or later, even the seasoned guys will stumble into something. Unfortunately, it takes years for seasoning to take place (and for some people longer than others) and seems unseasoned people spend 20-50% of their time on language itself instead of application logic

Comment: @DXM: The problem with programmers having to learn C++ for a long time before they don't make silly errors IME usually boils down to them having to unlearn wrong (C-like, C-With-Classes-like) techniques. So it is mostly a problem of bad education. C++ developers who learned doing it the _Right Way™_ from day one do not have that problem. Also, I would see it as an _advantage_, not a disadvantage, that C++ gives you all the necessary tools to do just about _anything_ you want.

Comment: @sbi: If most of the problems with C++ boil down to C-like techniques, then a possible solution is to remove (or deprecate) those C++ constructs that allow such techniques.

Comment: @Giorgio: No, they are needed to implement the other features. Inside `std::string` it's a very dangerous area to tread, but outside it's nice to use. Part of what makes C++ so great is that all of it can be written in C++. As a contrast, try to implement the BASIC string type in BASIC, Or Java's in Java.

Comment: @sbi: I do not see any problem in having library types or functions implemented in another language (see e.g. Python). Or one could implement the critical parts in (the current version of) C++ and then use compiler switches to forbid dangerous constructs in normal code that uses these libraries (use some kind of restricted C++ in normal code). In general, I think it is not a good idea to mix different abstraction levels in the same languages: this makes it too easy to introduce leaky abstractions in your code.

Comment: @Giorgio: Well, in any case, C++ _is_ that "other language" to do that in. If you remove the parts necessary for that, it would have to be done in C or assembler.

Comment: @sbi: I understand this, I just do not see it as an advantage. Implementing the tricky parts in C would be OK for me, and much cleaner (AFAIK this is the approach used for Python). BTW, I have been programming in C++ for a number of years, so I am not criticizing C++ coming from another language (e.g. I know very little Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like PHP was too high of a level for you and C++ was too low. I'm a C++ programmer myself and I do agree that sometimes signal-to-noise ratio, especially for a new person, can be quite low. It still has its place in many areas, but I would not use it for general programming.

The languages I would recommend would be C#, Python or Java.  Of those Java is at the end of the list because it seems like it's no longer the hot item in the industry and if you are going to learn something, might as well pick up a skill other people are looking for.

Both C# and Java are similar to syntax of C++, but they are less flexible which is a good and a bad thing. For you, its mostly a good thing since the flexibility is what introduces complexity.  Both languages will not allow you to pave over memory and will worry about allocations for you so you can focus on the actual logic.

Python is quite different and I'm not entirely sure how it compares in speed since I believe it is still interpreted whereas C# just-in-time compiles to machine code. But it is still a fun language.

Comment: Java fell second on language popularity (TIOBE)... behind C. So it's still hot especially with the big data wave coming.

Comment: @m3th0dman: Because TIOBE is such a *great* source of language popularity...

Comment: PHP isn't too high level, it's just very slow and impractical for what i want. Thank you for the answer i will give C# a look.

Answer (score 3):

If PHP is too slow for you, you can always write the performance sensitive parts in C++ and then call those C++ functions from PHP (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705443/how-to-mix-up-c-and-php)).

For relatively fast servers, Java and C# are also good options. They may not always be as fast as C++, but for most purposes they are "fast enough".

For some workloads, you may also hear that node.js is the fastest, but not in your case. Node.js specializes in I/O-bound operations, and you seem to be stuck in CPU-bound operations, so node.js would be "pretty fast, but not mind-blowingly so".

For C++, there are a number of things you could do to improve the situation. I suspect you might be doing something wrong if stack sizes are such a huge problem for you.

1. Pointers might be easier to handle if you try smart pointers.
2. Avoid manually allocating stuff if you can. If you want to allocate memory for a bunch of stuff, just use a vector and let C++'s STL do the complex stuff for you.

Finally, you might try a PHP compiler to accelerate PHP without needing to switch languages. See [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/), [phc](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) and [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php).

Try many different technologies and see what works for you.

If performance is *really* a major issue, and your calculations can be split into many smaller independent steps, then languages like OpenCL might help.

Comment: I've thought about some of those solutions before, thank you for answering